# control on backtracking

Tags: prolog

Assume that backtracking is done as shown below. Each end point show success or fail.

```
Ex:

    foo(X, search_key).

Backtracking :
                Root

              /   |  \
             /    |   \
            /     |    \
           /|\    |     \
          / | \   |    /|\
         /  f f   |   / | \
        /         |  f  |  f
       f          g     f

Abbreviation  f : fail
              g show first character of name
```

Unless no other way is found, I will not prefer to use g as argument in my next function.However, in this example, since no other way is found, I must use g as an argument in my next function.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to try all end points first and store them in a list (with `findall(foo...)` presumably), otherwise you won't know whether a non-g occurs later.

Then try to do the next function with the requirement that X is not g. If that fails, use g anyway.

```
avoidg(X) :-
    member(A,X),
    A \= f,
    A \= g,
    write(A).

avoidg(X):-
    member(A,X),
    A \= f, 
    write(A).
```

Example:

```
?- avoidg([f,f,f,g,f,f,f]).
g
true 

 ?- avoidg([f,f,f,g,f,f,h]).
h
true
```

Comment: I can not get how I should use findall. Can you explain more, or write a sample one ?

Comment: With your example, `findall(X, foo(X, search_key), Results)` would yield a list Results, with all values for X with which foo(X, search_key) succeeds. Again, with your example, and assuming you actually succeed with an 'f' value instead of failing, Results would equal [f,f,f,g,f,f,f], which can then be used in my answer above.

Comment: Junuxx, how can I take not of one function ex I have tried "not ( function())", but terminal emits the exception error message.

Comment: `not` works fine for me, but it might depend on your prolog implementation (I use SWI-Prolog 5.10). You could also try `\+function()`.

Comment: `not/1` is deprecated, you should use `(\+)/1`, or directly `(/=)/2`. Another good practice would be to separate IO from logic, here it'd mean handling `write/1` calls in a separate manner.

Comment: @Mog: Oh really? I like `not/1`, it's readable! :( About using `write/1` in a reasoning predicate, it was actually meant as a placeholder (OP: "I must use g as an argument in my next function") that can be replaced with whatever is necessary.

Comment: `not/1` is not readable, it's confusing at best: `not(not(A = b)), A = c.` returns `true` with `A = c` instead of `false` because `not/1` is not the `not` logical operator. It's the `not provable at this point in time` operator, hence the need for another name/symbol (`(\+)/1` is the way to go)! `dif/2` would even be better here :)

Comment: @Mog: Fair enough, I'll change the `not`s in my answer then, thanks! :)